# How to make a View(spinner) visible on keyBoard hide event in Android?

Tags: android, view, visibility, android-spinner

I have EditView a button and a Spinner in my layout. A picture is given below:

[image]

When I focus on the search field (EditText) I'm making the spinner (BrowseBy) disappear. Code is here:

```
    edTxt_SearchField.setOnFocusChangeListener
    (new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

                        if (edTxt_SearchField.hasFocus()) {
                            spnrBrowseBy.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                    }
                });
```

what happens here is that the softkeyBoard appears. also notice that spinner is gone.

[image]

When I press the backKey here, the softkeyboard is hiding. I want the spinner should reappear here also as in 1st image. Or is there any method which can detect the keyBoardHide event?

I have tried onConfiguration change method, has no effect. Note: I can't override the onBackPresskey() method also because my activity is extending the ActivityGroup class.

Comment: or is there any method of editText onFocusLose() or somthing like that.?

Comment: when keyboard will be hide on device back button, focus will remain on edittext so lost focus will not be helpful to you.

Comment: Hmm, yeah thats right Patik sharma. so u have any idea that how can i make the spinner visible again?

Comment: by the way is this method exist as u said like lost focus or somthing like that?

Comment: yes you can do that. Should I post small example for that, you can check that.  That may help you to make it work around.

Comment: Yes sure plz. i need an example

Comment: I have posted example for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the configChages in your manifest so that onConfigurationChage is called?

```
<activity android:name="TestActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboardHidden">
```

otherwise it should be just

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    spnrBrowseBy.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    spnrBrowseBy.requestLayout();
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Comment: should i add this android:configChanges="keyboardHidden" in the menifiest file while overriding the onConfigurationChanged(); method?

Answer (score 0):

By following way you can take actions on Got Focus and Lost Focus of your EditText.

```
yourEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus){
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Got Focus", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();            
        }else{
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lost Focus", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();           
        }
});
```

Hope this helps you.

Thanks.